# Get First Record of Each Group

Tags: sql, sql-server

First I would like to apologize if it is a basic question.

So, i have monitoring data being stored every 5 seconds.
I want create a query that returns me the first record every 10 minutes, for example:

```
|Data                    |  Voltage (V) |
|2020-08-14 14:00:00     |     10
|2020-08-14 14:00:05     |     15
|2020-08-14 14:00:00     |     12
....                     |
|2020-08-14 14:10:10     |     25
|2020-08-14 14:10:15     |     30
|2020-08-14 14:10:20     |     23
```

The desired result is:

```
|Data                  |Voltage (V)  |
|2020-08-14 14:00:00        10       |
|2020-08-14 14:10:10        25       |
```

I'm using SQLServer database.

I read about similar solutions as post: [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564)

But i can't resolve my issue.

I started with:

```
SELECT Data, Voltage
GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE,(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0 , Data)/10)*10,0)
ORDER BY DATA DESC
```

But i can't use FIRST() or top 1 in this query.

Anyone have ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by DATEADD(MINUTE,(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0 , Data)/10)*10,0) order by data) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```